# Show that the CDF of X~log(U/(1-U)) (with U uniform(0,1) is logistic

Tags: probability

I'm working through the book "Introduction to Probability" by Blitzstein and Hwang.
I'm reading about the generality of the uniform and there is an example where the task is to create a r.v. that has the logistic function as CDF. So the logistic function is inverted and a uniform variable U (uniform(0,1)) is plugged in into the inverted logistic function. Then the inverse computation is shown. It is shown that the logistic function is indeed the CDF of the previously created r.v. And there is a step in the calculation that I do not understand. It says that $P(U<=e^x(1-U))$ = $P(U<=e^x/(1+e^x))$. How is that obvious?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqlLs.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is straightforward calculus: $$U\le\mathrm e^x(1-U)\iff U\le\mathrm e^x-\mathrm e^xU\iff(1+\mathrm e^x)U\le\mathrm e^x\iff U\le\frac{\mathrm e^x}{1+\mathrm e^x}=\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{-x}}.$$

Comment: Okay - that is very straight forward indeed. Now I wonder how I did not see this. Thank you very much!